# Google Cloud Endpoints v2 custom domain with non-default app engine service

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gradle, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I have successfully deployed a Google Cloud Endpoints v2 API and a App Engine backend to `endpoint-dot-example.appspot.com` and I can see the metrics in the endpoints console.

build.gradle:

```
endpointsServer {
    hostname = "endpoint-dot-example.appspot.com"
}
```

appengine-web.xml:

```
<env-variables>
    <env-var name="ENDPOINTS_SERVICE_NAME" value="endpoint-dot-example.appspot.com"/>
</env-variables>
```

web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>endpoints-api-controller</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.google.api.control.extensions.appengine.GoogleAppEngineControlFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>endpoints.projectId</param-name>
        <param-value>example</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>endpoints.serviceName</param-name>
        <param-value>endpoint-dot-example.appspot.com</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

I now wish to serve this API from a custom domain.
For that I have routed a URL `api.example.com` to `example.appspot.com` at my registra and changed the hostname in build.gradle:

```
endpointsServer {
    hostname = "api.example.com"
}
```

But I am getting 404 error when making requests with the custom domain. I can also see the logs in the stackdriver logging for the default service. 
How can I tell app engine to route the requests to the API?

**Edit 1**
This is the 404 response body:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    <title>404 NOT_FOUND</title>
</head>
<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
    <h1>Error: NOT_FOUND</h1>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you show what the 404 error format looks like?

Comment: @saiyr I have edited my question with the response body

Comment: @Heigo Did you make any progress on this? I'm in the exact same situation.

Comment: @Jeremy No progress

Answer (score 0):

The way around this is to use a custom base path for your Endpoints API.

It appears `/_ah/` URLs can bypass dispatch rules from `dispatch.yaml`, especially with non-default services. But with a custom base path that isn't `/_ah/`, they work fine.

Here is an example, in Python, of a non-default service running an API at `api.example.com/api/v1/*`.

app.yaml:

```
- url: .*
  script: api.app
```

api.py:

```
api_collection = endpoints.api(
    name='api',
    version='v1',
    base_path='/',
    description='Example API',
    api_key_required=False,
    scopes=[],
    audiences=[])

app = endpoints.api_server([api_collection])
```

dispatch.yaml:

```
# Send requests to api.example.com to the "api" service
- url: "api.example.com/*"
  service: api
```